# Python Filtering Excel Data with pandas by partial match

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter an excel spreadsheet using pandas and save the filtered data to a new worksheet. Currently I have this which works as expected

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name=0) #reads the first sheet of your excel file

df = df[(df['CodedCorporation'] == 'lucy')] #Filtering dataframe

df.to_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='new data') #Saving to a new sheet called Filtered Data
```

The problem is that this code looks for an exact match of the word "Lucy" in the column titled "CodedCorporation". What I need is to be able to filter based on partial matches not exact matches.

So I tried this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name=0) #reads the first sheet of your excel file

df = df[('lucy' in df['CodedCorporation'])] #Filtering dataframe

df.to_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='new data') #Saving to a new sheet called Filtered Data
```

But that spits out a error.

Can someone help explain how to make this look for partial matches in the column and not a exact match? Kind of like how when you are working in excel and you type a word into the filter, excel shows everything that contains that word.

Comment: look at this to get partial matches https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method with a lambda to run row-wise logic.

Instead of this:

```
df = df[('lucy' in df['CodedCorporation'])] #Filtering dataframe
```

You can create a flag like "lucy_ind":

```
df["lucy_ind"] = df.apply(lambda x: True if 'lucy' in x['CodedCorporation'] else False, axis=1)
```

... and then to filter it (only include lines where lucy is in CodedCorporation)... you'd just do:

```
df = df[df["lucy_ind"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` function from `str` property as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        "has lucy",
         "also has lucy in it",
         "this line doesn't"
    ],
    columns=["CodedCoporation"]
)

filtered_df = df[df.CodedCoporation.str.contains('lucy')]

filtered_df.to_markdown()
```

|  | CodedCoporation |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | has lucy |
| 1 | also has lucy in it |

Comment: worked beautifully. Thank you much.